# How to replace URL parameter by element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some elements on page where I want to get displayed with of each element of certain class and put it to an URL parameter by replacing a string.

Sorry I am a JS newbie!

HTML for objects on page is like:

```
<div class="getwidth" style="background-image: url('//domain.de/picture1.jpg?w=putwidth');">...
</div>

<div class="getwidth" style="background-image: url('//domain.de/picture2.jpg?w=putwidth');">...
</div>
```

jQuery onload function:

```
jQuery('.getwidth').each(function() {
    var wrapper = jQuery(this);
    var width   = wrapper.width();
    wrapper.html(wrapper.html().replace(new RegExp(/putwidth/, 'g'), width));
});
```

Wanted output example if element is 245px wide:

```
<div class="getwidth" style="background-image: url('//domain.de/picture2.jpg?w=245');">...
</div>
```

Getting the element width seems to work. Replacing the string doesn´t.

Comment: And what happens when I resize the browser, or on mobile rotate my screen?

Comment: Thank for the comment! With this usecase one would have to deal with that later by adding min-sizes, reloading or by refirering the script. All 3 might not be a nice one, but our statistics show, that people don´t rotate back and forth or resize window so often. If they do, most users do it once - that might be so only on our sites

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` with `css`:

```
wrapper.css("background-image", wrapper.css("background-image").replace(/putwidth/g, width));
```

Comment: That would work I think. Thank you!!! But I´m looking for a more flexible way, that I can fire on IMG as well. So firering on BACKGROUND is not the solution yet.  My usecase would be :: Get idth of element with class GETWIDTH and replace string "PUTWIDTH" within or of this element

like
`IMG CLASS="GETWIDTH" SRC="image.jpg?w=PUTWIDTH`
or
`DIV CLASS="GETWIDTH" 
IMG SRC="image.jpg?w=PUTWIDTH
/DIV`